# The intervals $(2,4)$ and $(-1,17)$ have the same cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove that $(2,4)$ and $(-1,17)$ have the same cardinality. 
I have the definition of cardinality but my prof words things in the most confusing way possible. Help!

Comment: Try to find a linear function, i.e. a line from $(2,4)$ to $(-1,17)$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, an *affine* function, $x\mapsto ax+b$. ($b$ will be nonzero.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a bijective function $f\colon (2,4)\rightarrow (-1,17)$. As suggested in the comments, try with a function of the form $f(x) = ax+b$.

You know that the interval $(2,4)$ of length $2$ should be stretched out to fit onto the interval $(-1,17)$, which has length $18$. In other words,
$$a = 18/2 = 9.$$
But $f(x) = 9x$ doesn't work. It maps $(2,4)$ to $(18,36)$, so you need to adjust $f$ by adding some number $b$, i.e. you need to find $b$, such that $f(x) = 9x+b$ maps $(2,4)$ to the correct interval.

When you have found a function that maps to the right place, you need to check that it is indeed a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to show two sets $X,Y$ have the same cardinality is to show that there is a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ that is both 1) injective and 2) surjective. That is  1) for all $a\neq b\in X$ we must have $f(a)\neq f(b)$ and 2) for all $y\in Y$ there must exist $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.